# Is there any way to find out the ruby version used by a past heroku release?

Tags: ruby, heroku

My Gemfile, until now, was not [specifying an explicit ruby version](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2012/5/9/multiple_ruby_version_support_on_heroku). After a recent deploy, I ran into a bug because of a difference in BigDecimal#new between 1.9.2 and 1.9.3. I could be crazy, but it really seems like heroku moved me backwards from 1.9.3 to 1.9.2. Is there any way I can extract the ruby version of a previous release from heroku? It doesn't seem to be in heroku releases:info. Going forward I specified 1.9.3 in my Gemfile and that fixed the problem.

I'm wondering if this is somehow related to heroku recently defaulting to ruby 2.0.

Comment: Sounds like an odd behaviour. Let us know your findings. I'd be surprised if it was something heroku did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's somewhat crude, but you could [roll back](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/releases#rollback) to the previous release and do

```
$ heroku run bash
$ ruby --version
```

Comment: That's true, I could do that on my staging server without causing any disruption. think i'll try that.